# I did instaled ubuntu on inspiron b120 but can not connect to internet

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I try to connect tru wi-fi and also tru dsl cable, but I have not been able to connect yet. it waas connecting just fine when running on windows, I am really new to ubuntu so any advise I can get will be apreciated.

I installed: Ubuntu 12.04 lts
laptop has: 2 gb ram and intel celeron m procesor 1.40GHz

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved with using the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

hope it can help somebody else.